# Css and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to add 'input' inside ul list in form-group div.
But, everytime i click at textarea, dropdown move up. I want to make dropdown remains when click on the input.

```
<div class="form-group">
      <a class="btn btn-default btn-select">
            <input class="btn-select-input" id="" name="" value="Option 2" type="hidden">
            <span class="btn-select-value">Purpose of Enquiry</span>
            <span class="btn-select-arrow glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>
            <ul style="display: none;">
                <li>Career Enquiries</li>
                <li>Data Protection Feedback</li>
                <li>Media & Publications</li>
                <li>New Business Collaborations<input class="dropinput" type="text" placeholder="Please specify project location"></li>
                <li>Others<input class="dropinput" type="text" placeholder="Please specify"></li>
            </ul>
        </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: `<input>` is an invalid child for `<li>`. You want to take it out of the `<ul>` element. Though for that matter, you don't want `<ul>` and `<li>` elements **at all**. You're more likely looking for **`<select>`** and **`<option>`** elements :)

Comment: I dont get u sir.

Comment: You need to use `select` for acquiring this

Comment: @ObsidianAge The [<li> content model](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element) is "flow", and [<input> elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element) can be categorized as flow or phrasal.  so they should be valid child elements of <li>. Saying that the content model in which <input> is expected is "phrasal" is non normative and [covers both phrasal and flow in this context](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#element-dfn-contexts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**`<input>` is an invalid child for `<li>`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element).

Having said that, you're probably not looking for `<ul>` and `<li>` elements **at all**. You're trying to present the user with a selection, and as such, you're looking to make use of  **`<select>`** and **`<option>`** elements.

You want the first input to display when the user selects a project, and the second input to display when the user selects `Others`. To achieve this, set the `display` of both elements to `none` by default. Then **show** the target element based on the selection, and **hide** the other elements at the same time using jQuery:

```js
var selection = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
selection.onchange = function() {
  if (selection.value == 'Others') {
    $('#specify').show();
    $('#project').hide();
  }
  else {
    $('#project').show();
    $('#specify').hide();
  }
}
```

```css
#specify {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="form-group">
  <span class="btn-select-value">Purpose of Enquiry</span>
  <select>
      <option>Career Enquiries</option>
      <option>Data Protection Feedback</option>
      <option>Media & Publications</option>
      <option>New Business Collaborations</option>
      <option>Others</option>
    </select>
  <input id="project" class="dropinput" type="text" placeholder="Please specify project location">
  <input id="specify" class="dropinput" type="text" placeholder="Please specify">
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: the design requirement is like..

input is beside selection.. and can add content to that input when selected

Comment: It sounds like my example perfectly adheres to your design requirement; whenever you make a selection the input appears to the right of the selection. However, I've just modified the code so that the `#project` input is visible **by default**.

Comment: appear correctly but dont know how to disable to avoid move up when click on input

Comment: ^ Can you please expand on "*disable to avoid move up when click on input*"? There is nothing to 'disable', and the elements don't change shape at all, so I'm unsure what you're trying to move up. Are you asking how you can shrink the size of the input box so that they appear flush at the bottom?

Comment: thanks for ur time.

when click, selection will appears. In some selection, there is input to type beside them. when click to that input, i can type content.

currently, its nope happen. Its back to top when select.

Comment: In my above example, this is not the case -- all five possible options have the input box appear next to them. If that is **not** the case for your code, work from mine as a **basis**. For further help, it would really help if you update your question to showcase all **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: when I click on the input field, the dropdown closes.

Comment: alrite, tq sir.

Comment: That is **intended** behaviour for `<select>`, and cannot be undone. Once you're happy this solution solves your problem, please don't forget to accept this answer by clicking on the grey check below the vote buttons -- this removes it from the 'Unanswered Questions' queue, and awards reputation to both the question asker and question answerer. You'll be able to do that 15 minutes after asking any question. Of course, in saying that, you are under no obligation to mark my answer or anyone else's answer as correct, though it does help to keep things on StackOverflow flowing smoothly :)